# Why should string length be plus one its capacity in C?

Tags: c, string, indexing

Your string length should be one more than the maximum number of characters you want it to be able to hold. Logical enough: strings are terminated with a `NULL` character.

It's a very general advice that most newbies get. However, as I grew in programming, now it seems that it's not so correct.

The indexing of *any* type of array, be it `int` or `char`, starts from `0`. The maximum index value of most arrays, therefore, is one less than its numerical value. It's same with a string, but since it has an extra character at the end, it gets incremented by one. So, the string length is the same as the number of characters in it.

---

To see if I'm right, see this snippet:

```
char str[9];
scanf("%s", str);
printf("%d", strlen(str));
```

Make this a full-fledged program, and run it. Type `123456789`, a guaranteed 9-character long text, and see the results. It could hold the string and sure enough, the string length is `9`.

---

I even witnessed many expert programmers saying that string size should be plus one its capacity. Is this advice largely a myth, or I am going wrong somewhere?

### EDIT

Let's say I want to create an integer array `Arr` that can hold `x` number of elements. The index value of `Arr`'s last element will be one less than `x` since index values start from `0` and not `1`. So, its length is `x-1`.

How would you declare it then? I'd do that like this: `int Arr[x-1];`. I don't think there's any issues with this.

Now if `Arr` were a `char` type array (i.e. a string), the length of `Arr` would be one more than that of its `int` counterpart since it has an extra NULL character at the end. This will end up as: `(x-1)+1=x`.

[Code to demonstrate this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424481/string-size-should-be-plus-one-its-capacity/43424746#43424746)

So why does the declaration this time has to be `char Arr[x+1]` and not simply `char Arr[x]`?

Comment: Can you share the link to the so called experts who say space for '\0' should not be reserved.

Comment: Also the program you showed invokes *Undefined Behavior*. Why it works or does not work is not a valid question.

Comment: See e. g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/): scanf adds automatically a terminating 0 character. So if you do so as described in your question, you are actually writing beyond the bounds of your array -> UB!

Comment: C does not have a string type. And it is not clear why the array length (which is not the same as its size!) is one less - less than what? What is the "numerical value" of an array??

Comment: Why don't you ask a clear question and show some research instead of stating confused things?

Comment: @Olaf Google `numerical value`.

Comment: //All array sizes, therefore, are one less than their numerical values.// This makes no sense. An array of length 5 has indices from 0 to 4, and a size of 5 because there are 5 elements.

Comment: The problem is not the term, but the context you use it for. So I ask once more: what is the numerical value **of an array**?

Comment: It's `array size`, not just `array`. What is the penultimate index of a string?

Comment: Does the wording matter? The question can be edited. The wrong usage of a term is not the end of the world.

Comment: `char str[9]; scanf("%s", str); /*the user may enter 8 characters (need 1 char for the terminating '\0'), or your program is undefined*/` 
`printf("%d", strlen(str)); /*oops, you're printing a size_t wrong -- your program is undefined */`.  `scanf("%s", ...)` should never be used in C, and you need to be careful with vararg functions such as `printf`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I said experts say to reserve a space for NULL character, not the other way around.

Comment: People are downvoting this because you're basically asking, "Why does something which is not guaranteed to do anything in particular doing this particular thing?" One of the things that it could do is work perfectly. Another thing it could do is segfault. It could wipe your hard drive. Undefined behavior means that the program can do whatever it wants. (NB: I didn't downvote, because it's better to ask "why is this necessary" than assume it isn't and have to find heisenbugs later on, but that's why people would.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right about the indexing. However:

```
char str[9];
```

When you declare a string this way, the number `9` is the **array length**. Minus the NULL, there can be only 8 characters, not 9. The length of an array is the number of elements in the array, NOT the *maximum index value* as you think. You're confusing these terms.

Why your program works is already explained by many other answers and even comments.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard relative to the description of the conversion specifier `s` (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> s Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.279) If no l length
>   modiﬁer is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the
>   sequence and **a terminating null character, which will be added
>   automatically**.

So if to enter the sequence of characters `123456789` then there will be an attempt to write the following characters `

```
{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '\0' }`
```

in the array declared like

```
char str[9];
```

As it is seen the sequence contains 10 characters while the array can accommodate only 9 characters. So the memory beyond the array will be overwritten and as result the program has undefined behavior.

In C opposite to C++ you can initialize a character array the following way

```
char str[3] = "Bye";
```

In this case the terminating zero will not be used as an initializer of the array. That is the array will not contain a string but just characters

```
{ 'B', 'y', 'e' }
```

However you may not apply the standard C function `strlen` to this array because the function counts characters until the terminating zero is encountered and the array does not have such a character.

You should distinguish the value returned by the `sizeof` operator and the value returned by the standard C function `strlen`.

For example if you have a declaration like this

```
char str[10] = "Hello";
```

then the `sizeof` operator `sizeof( str )` returns 10 that is the array has 10 elements of the size equal 1 (`sizeof( char)` is always equal to 1).

However if you will apply the standard C function `strlen`  then the returned value will be equal to 5 because the function counts all characters before the terminating zero.

You can write for example

```
str[8] = 'A';
```

Nevertheless if ypu apply the function `strlen` you will again get the value 5 because before the element `str[8]` with the value `'A'` there is a terminating zero.

Answer (score 2):

> The indexing of any type of array, be it int or char, starts from 0.

Yes, that's true.

> All array sizes, therefore, are one less than their numerical values.

No. The first value used for indexing only affects the indexing, not the size. For example, a 1-sized array has just one index, 0. It's the maximum index value that is one less than the size, not the other way around.

In a declaration `char str[9];` the value 9 is the array size, not the maximum index value.

The reason that your example *seems* to work, is that undefined behavior does not *have* to result in a crash or error message.

Comment: Does the wording matter? The question can be edited. The wrong usage of a term is not the end of the world.

Comment: I think you used the terms correctly? What are you referring to?

Comment: That it will be `maximum index value` instead of `array size`. it's clear I meant that! Why is everyone being so fussy about this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that the array index begins at 0, but a char str[9] has a lenght of 9, so the highest index is 8. Your example seems to work, but it could easily create an error. You can also type 1234567890 in your code and it would output 10, because the program can't know the lenght of the array.

When you define that char array, you create a 9 byte space for it on the stack, but when you pass it to scanf the char[] gets converted to a char* a pointer to the first element in the array. So scanf can't know the length of the array and writes the input in the memory, begining at the location where str points to. It writes the \0 character outside of the space that is reserved for the array! But again when pass it to strlen, it can't see the size of the array and continues to scan memory for a \0, which it finds after 10 bytes, so it assumes a length of 10.

Like @Ajay Brahmakshatriya showed in his answer this can lead to errors, because the space outside of the string can be used for another variable, e.g. another string, which then can write different data to the byte where the \0 has been.

Answer (score 0):

See this -> [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IAdwL5)

```
int main(void) {
    char a[16];
    char b[16];
    scanf("%s",a);
    b[0]='a';
    b[1]='\0';
    printf("%s %d %p %p", a, strlen(a), a, b);
    return 0;  
}
```

This is an almost replica of the code you showed. For the given input of 16 length (the array size of also 16), the length printed is 17.

Now that we have established that what you said is not correct, we will look at why it printed 9 for you and not in the example I posted.

You created am array of size 9 (allocated 9 bytes).
Then you stored 9 bytes of data into it and terminated it by `'\0'` which wrote on the tenth byte. Since that space was not used by *anything* (luckily) important, the data fit.

Then when you called `strlen`, it gave you 9.

Now I made an array of 16 bytes and followed it with another array which is placed after it. Now when it read 16 bytes and terminated it with `'\0'` it wrote into b.

I overwrote it again by writing to b.
The `'\0'` written by `scanf` was thus gone.

Then the `strlen` when counting the length overflowed into b and stopped when it saw the `'\0'` at `b[1]`.

All of this is ofcourse *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

> ...So, the string length is the same as the number of characters in it.

This statement is correct, if we see the terminating null not as a character. However, the storage needed to hold the *string* is one more than the number of characters in it. (The emphasis on 'string' is because string as a data type requires the additional terminating null, which requires storage.)

Comment: I'm talking about index, not the size.

Answer (score -1):

An attempt at proving my point:

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[23];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("String length = %d\n", strlen(str));
    printf("String element  ---  Index number");
    int index=0;

    while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
        printf("\n%c  ---  %d", str[i], index);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nNULL  ===  %d", index);

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Input

```
graphing
```

### Sample Output

```
String length = 8
String element  ---  Index number
g  ---  0
r  ---  1
a  ---  2
p  ---  3
h  ---  4
i  ---  5
n  ---  6
g  ---  7
NULL  ===  8
```

Comment: What is your point? An 8-letter string + NULL terminator is a total of 9 bytes. An array definition to hold that string is `char str[9]` and the valid array indices are 0..8. An array of `int` is not a C string (no NULL terminator required) so an array of 8 `int` would be `int arr[8]` and the valid indices are 0..7. All the other posted answers are correct.